# How do I solve the NameError: name 'randomResponce' is not defined

Tags: python, nameerror

This the code that has the error:

```
print("Through 1-10 write a number that is going to represent how far you should throw the ball for " + playerCMD4 + "to catch") ; sleep(float(speed))
                    playerNumberCMD = raw_input()
                    import random
                    def allResponses(arg1):
                            allResponses = arg1
                    allResponses = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
                    def randomResponse(arg1):
                            randomResponse = arg1
                    randomResponse = random.choice(allResponses)
                    if randomResponce == playerNumberCMD:
                            print(playerCMD4 + " caught the ball.") ; sleep(float(speed))
```

The error I get is this:
Traceback (most recent call last):

```
  File "classref3.py", line 3, in <module>
    class Dog:
  File "classref3.py", line 50, in Dog
    if randomResponce == playerNumberCMD:
NameError: name 'randomResponce' is not defined
```

Was `Def`not the correct way to go or is it something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error states you have not defined the variable "randomResponce".

If you look at the previous line where you think you have defined the variable, you have defined "randomResponse".  Note the different spelling. The spelling needs to be the same.

I would also caution against using the same name for a variable and a function in the same script.